# How to sort a collection of objects, which has to be sorted based on some constantly changing parameters

Tags: c#, list, sorting, weighted

I'm looking on how to sort a list effectively using weighted values.

Each item has an id, name and filepath. Each item also has a list of values which are assigned a percentage, showing how relevant they are to each value.

I need the list to be sorted so that the items which are at the top end of the list are the ones which are the most relevant to the current parameters.

Lets say,

Item One:

- A: 50, B: 30, C : 20, D : 10
- X : 50, Z :20

Item Two:

- A:100, B:0, C:0, D:0
- X:0, Z:100

And my parameters are A and Z. Clearly Item Two should be at the top of my list as it's the most relevant item. But how would I go about implementing this?

Bonus: Would be nice to be able to have a slight randomisation as well, I don't want to be served the definitive relevant item each time.

Thanks

Comment: More information please. What have you tried? How will you calculate the value of each item for the purposes of sorting? Will you add the parameters? Multiply them? Are you storing the items in a `List<T>`? `List<T>` has a method `Sort` that takes a delegate. Have you tried using that?

Comment: You want a random sort? How does that make sense?

Comment: Well I want it sorted, so I get more relevant items. But I don't want the most relevant every single time, so there needs to be a slight element of randomness. I've previously used the List<T>.Sort method but I wasn't sure if that was the best practice for this type of problem.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a Priority Queue.  C# doesn't have one built in, but if you search around for that term you'll find lots of people providing their own implementations as it's a common practical and academic problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know your weighting function, you could use Linq to Objects:

```
var sorted = (from o in myList orderby o.SortingValue select o).ToList();
```

In this example, `SortingValue` would be a property on the object that encapsulates the attributes in your question and would implement your algorithm.

Sample algorithm for SortingValue:

You could use a Dictionary to hold relevance percentages

Then, your "current parameters" could be used as keys to the Dictionary to get the relevant weighting:

```
Dictionary<string, double> weightDictionary = // Load somehow

double SortingValue
{
    get {
        double sortingValue;

        foreach(string currentParameter in currentParameters)
        {
            sortingValue += weightDictionary[currentParameter];
        }

        // You could use Math.Random to get a number between say -0.1 and -.1.  
        // Multiply sortingValue by that random number.
        return sortingValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an update that this was pretty similar to how I sorted it, cheers for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I created an extension method just for this purpose. I've just came across the need for it again:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByWeight<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TKey, int> weighting) where TKey : IComparable
{
    Dictionary<TSource, int> order = new Dictionary<TSource, int>();
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        if (!order.ContainsKey(item)) order.Add(item, weighting(keySelector(item)));
    }
    return source.OrderBy(s => order[s]);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var data = dt.Select(g => new
{
    Season = g.season,
    AverageTemp = g.temp
}).OrderByWeight(a => a.Season, x =>
{
    if (x == "WINTER") return 1;
    if (x == "SPRING") return 2;
    if (x == "SUMMER") return 3;
    if (x == "AUTUMN") return 4;
    return 99;
});
```

Source: [from my old blog](http://www.skindog.co.uk/2009/03/18/custom-sorting-order-in-linq-order-by-weighting/)